# When to delete files from NSCachesDirectory

Tags: ios

I am developing a news application . I am using NSCacheDirectory to save to image's . I want to know when should I delete the images from the cash . I know I could probably delete it when I receive a memory warning (or it would be automatically deleted in a low memory condition) but I don't understand why to keep the images for so long and delete them only if I receive the memory warning . I also tried to check if all the images saved in NSCashDirectory are in the data which I get (from the internet) and if not then delete it , but I am sure performance would be a issue . Is there a way to clear cash after a specific time interval

P.S. I am quite new to iOS programming .

Comment: Are you confusing disk storage with memory storage?

Comment: Please excuse me if I am wrong , will NSCashDirectory not use disk memory.

Comment: You could try clearing the NSCacheDirectory when the user quits the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are developing a news application I am going to assume that the news will be updated at certain intervals. This means that you could probably define a lifetime for an article stored on the device. So what you could do is say every day, mark all articles older than seven days as trashable. Then, when it's safe to do so (App launch or when user is reading new content) you can delete said content.

I don't know your audience but traditionally it's safe to assume that people won't read the same article multiple times so you can definitely make your window for stale content quite small.

That being said if you implement a bookmarking facility you could approach this in a similar fashion too. You could for instance assume that the user will most likely interact with the most recently bookmarked articles. Remember, in this recency is defined by the user not the article date. Articles bookmarked most recently by the user will possibly be read or shared more likely than older ones.

You could also have an option in your setting where the user can choose to delete all cached content. Since your content should be living on a server it shouldn't be impossible for the user to fetch old content.

As far as you are concerned each article could be broken up into an article mapping and an article. An article mapping should contain the bare minimum of information to allow for the display of content in an article feed (things like headline, thumbnail URL etc). Where your article would contain all the content. When the user requests to delete all cached data you could delete all the images and keep all the mappings (at least the most recent ones) on the device still.

Happy coding